# How do i write to a program that show system`s time in java language?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Time {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {   
        Date myDate=new Date();
        int hours=myDate.getHours();
        int minutes=myDate.getMinutes();
        int seconds=myDate.getSeconds();
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is NOT JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for this. Don't use `java.util.Date` for `getHours()` since those are deprecated.

```
  Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
  System.out.println(calendar.getTime()); // get time will give you current time
```

Out put:

```
  Fri Sep 19 12:23:48 IST 2014
```

You should read about `Calendar`, you can find all you need there.

For your comment. If you only want Time part you can use [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Eg:

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();    
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(df.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Out put:

```
12:32:08
```

Or you can get current hour, minute and seconds too.

Eg:

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("current hour: "+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
System.out.println("current minute: "+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
System.out.println("current second: " +calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Out put:

```
current hour: 12
current minute: 48
current second: 8
```

Comment: excuse me but i want to just time

Comment: @atf read my edit. You can get any part form calender.

Comment: excuse me but i want to just time

Comment: @atf `12:32:08` is time. What is your expected out put?

Comment: Gayan Ranaweei i want to a program that just time

Comment: @atf time means hour and minutes ? Just show us in a example

Comment: yes time means hour and minutes and secound

Comment: @atf read my new edit

Comment: please you to explain this code...

Comment: @atf first read all linked article( `Java` docs). Then try to do something by your own. Then you will know how and why.